# Why does the max_depth answer change every time I run in GridSearchCV for decision tree?

Tags: python

```
Hyperparameters={'max_depth':np.arange(1,100,1)}

dectree= tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

cv_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator= dectree ,param_grid = Hyperparameters, scoring ='accuracy',cv = 10)

cv_grid= cv_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

cv_grid.best_params_
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Have you had the chance to consider my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is randomness in the decision tree algorithm. From the [Decision Tree documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html):

> The features are always randomly permuted at each split, even if splitter is set to "best". But the best found split may vary across different runs, even if `max_features=n_features`. That is the case, if the improvement of the criterion is identical for several splits and one split has to be selected at random.

So, randomness is normal. If you want a deterministic approach, set the `random_state` parameter (i.e., specify the seed) and you will get the same results every time. Here's an example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree

X_train = np.random.rand(100, 10)
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 3, 100)

for i in range(10):
    Hyperparameters={'max_depth':np.arange(1,100,1)}
    dectree= tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
    cv_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator= dectree ,param_grid = Hyperparameters, 
                           scoring ='accuracy',cv = 5)
    cv_grid= cv_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(cv_grid.best_params_)
```

```
{'max_depth': 4}
{'max_depth': 4}
{'max_depth': 4}
{'max_depth': 4}
{'max_depth': 4}
```

When I did a test run **without** using the `random_state` argument, I was getting the following:

```
{'max_depth': 5}
{'max_depth': 65}
{'max_depth': 59}
{'max_depth': 5}
{'max_depth': 93}
```